# is there a way to let an background app display something when other app is running?

Tags: android, iphone

for example,  if i'm playing a game, a trigger will display an alert after a certain  time to warn me not playing too much time and should have  a rest. 
Both android and iphone solution is welcome.

Comment: On ios you could use [Local notifications](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/13773123/how-can-i-schedule-local-notification-for-the-following-scenario)

Answer (score 1, accepted):

On Android, using the following permission,

```
<uses-permission android:name="android.permission.SYSTEM_ALERT_WINDOW"/>
```

you can draw views on top of any other application. For example, this is the permission used by the Facebook Home app to draw [its chat heads](http://www.piwai.info/chatheads-basics/).

Also, this is a system permission, so it does come at a cost.

Answer (score 1):

Think about it as on an Alarm Clock, which can interrupt your current App, something which is off-course possible.

Regarding Android you might want to read about [AlarmManager](http://developer.android.com/reference/android/app/AlarmManager.html)

As for iPhone you might want to take a look in this [Stackoverflow question](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/4119943/iphone-is-it-possible-to-register-my-application-so-the-os-notifies-it-every-x-s) discussing local notifications.

Answer (score 1):

(Android solution)

You could use AlarmManager with setRepeating function to repeat this task

Check [here](http://developer.android.com/reference/android/app/AlarmManager.html)

Hope it helps :)